# Image flash alt tag for a split second before showing in next js

Tags: next.js, netlify, nextjs-image

After deploying my first app with next js to netlify I noticed that when you reload the page the image flash the alt tag of that image for a split second before showing the image itself. Now I have only noticed the error when I deploy the site to netlify and I wonder if there is some issue with deployment or just that on localhost the error is to fast to notice. Here is the site were the image flash alt tag:

https://6329df86f476dc4f00c5fa95--bucolic-heliotrope-ec5e6e.netlify.app/

And this is the source code for the project: https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/demo

So basically the question is if im doing something wrong or if it is possible to load the images before the page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code as text directly to the question, and [format it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).